Split text into lines without using line-clamp
I am generating multiple words from a JSON file and want to display only two lines at once, currently I am using line clamps but it truncates the last word of the second line. If the word is being truncated I want it to move to the next line. Is it possible to implement this?
                 <div className="box">
                    <p className="word">
                        {wordList.map((word, wordIndex) => {
                            const currWord = typedHistory[wordIndex] || "";
                            const isCurrentWord = wordIndex === typedHistory.length;
                            const hasWrongChars = currWord.split("").some((char, index) => char !== word[index]);
                            const isExcessLength = currWord.length > word.length;
                            const isIncomplete = currWord.length >= 0 && currWord.length < word.length && typedHistory.includes(currWord);
                            const shouldHighlightWordRed = hasWrongChars || isExcessLength || isIncomplete;
                            return (
                                <span key={wordIndex} ref={isCurrentWord ? currentWordRef : null}>
                                    {word.split("").map((char, charIndex) => {
                                        let charColor = "#fff";

                                        if (wordIndex < typedHistory.length) {
                                            charColor = shouldHighlightWordRed ? "red" : "var(--main-color)";
                                        } else if (isCurrentWord) {
                                            const typedChar = typedChars[charIndex] || "";
                                            charColor = typedChar === char ? "var(--main-color)" : typedChar !== "" ? "red" : "#fff";
                                        }
                                        return (
                                            <span key={charIndex} style={{ color: charColor }}>{char}</span>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    {' '}
                                </span>
                            );
                        })}
                    </p>
                </div>

CSS:
.box {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  background-color: var(--sub-alt-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-height: 8.5em;  
  height: 8.5em;
  user-select: none;

}
.box .word {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
          line-clamp: 2; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

How I am generating text
 useEffect(() => {
        import("../../public/english.json").then((words) =>
            dispatch(setWordList(words.default))
        );
    }, [dispatch]);

I am expecting the behavior  of text like in this case: typetest.io
Here is a reproducible example: codesandbox

I found a solution by removing line-clamp and making max-height = 2*line-height
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const currentWordRef = useRef(null);
  const [wordList, setWordList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    import("./english.json").then((words) => setWordList(words.default));
  });
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        width: "100%",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "green",
      }}
    >
      <div className="test">
        <div className="box">
          <p className="word">
            {wordList.map((word, wordIndex) => {
              return (
                <span key={wordIndex}>
                  {word.split("").map((char, charIndex) => {
                    let charColor = "#fff";
                    return (
                      <span key={charIndex} style={{ color: charColor }}>
                        {char}
                      </span>
                    );
                  })}{" "}
                </span>
              );
            })}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 62vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 58rem;
  width: 58rem;
}

.box {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 8.5em;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}

.box .word {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: normal; /* Ensure words wrap correctly */
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-height: 3em; /* Limit to 2 lines */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow beyond the second line */
}

.box .word {
  display: inline-block;
}

Here is the demo

You can simply set the block height to 2lh and overflow:hidden. Showed the difference in the example:


div {
  width: 248px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  outline: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  &:nth-child(1) {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    height: 2lh;
  }
}
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, commodi!</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, commodi!</div>




The solution worked for plain text but in my case where I am getting words from another file and displaying it in the form of words and characters it didn't work

Perhaps you can share an example, because it is difficult to understand from words exactly what did not work.

sure I will give an example

Here, the last word of the 2nd line gets truncated with the updated code https://codesandbox.io/embed/w456br?view=editor+%2B+preview&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx

any update on the example?

in example you apply -webkit-line-clamp
